# Como pegar algo de um input text e passar por referencia?

Tags: javascript, react

Como eu faço para pegar algo que digitei num input text, e ao pressionar um botão "Send", eu envio esse texto para algum lugar do meu codigo, tipo como usamos 'this.state.algumaCoisa'... Segue o codigo:

```
render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
      <div className="box box-primary direct-chat direct-chat-primary ">
  <Chat />
      <div nameClass="direct-chat-msg right">
          <div className="direct-chat-info clearfix">
              <span className="direct-chat-name pull-right">TEXTO AQUI</span>
              <span className="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">TEXTO AQUI</span>
          </div>
              <img className="direct-chat-img-right" alt="message user image"/>
      </div>

        <div className="box-footer">
         <div className="input-group">
                    <input
                    ref="topic"
                    type="text"
                    name="message"
                    placeholder="Type your message here..."
                    className="form-control"/>
<span className="input-group-btn">                     
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-flat btn-primary">Send</button>
            </span>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer isso de maneiras diferentes. Uma delas é ir guardando o valor do input ouvindo eventos `input`, e aí o valor já está no `state` à espera de ser usado:

```js
const Chat = () => null;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      texto: ''
    }
  }

  onSend() {
    console.log(this.state.texto);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="box box-primary direct-chat direct-chat-primary ">
          <Chat />
          <div nameClass="direct-chat-msg right">
            <div className="direct-chat-info clearfix">
              <span className="direct-chat-name pull-right">TEXTO AQUI</span>
              <span className="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">TEXTO AQUI</span>
            </div>
            <img className="direct-chat-img-right" alt="message user image" />
          </div>

          <div className="box-footer">
            <div className="input-group">
              <input onInput={(e) => this.setState({texto: e.target.value})} type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type your message here..." className="form-control"/>
              <span className="input-group-btn">                     
                  <button type="button" onClick={this.onSend.bind(this)} className="btn btn-flat btn-primary">Send</button>
                  </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Outra maneira é usar `ref` como tinhas. Nesse caso diz a documentação que deves usar `ref` de maneira assíncrona. Ficaria assim:

```js
const Chat = () => null;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  onSend() {
    const value = this.textInput.value;
    console.log(value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="box box-primary direct-chat direct-chat-primary ">
          <Chat />
          <div nameClass="direct-chat-msg right">
            <div className="direct-chat-info clearfix">
              <span className="direct-chat-name pull-right">TEXTO AQUI</span>
              <span className="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">TEXTO AQUI</span>
            </div>
            <img className="direct-chat-img-right" alt="message user image" />
          </div>

          <div className="box-footer">
            <div className="input-group">
              <input ref={input => this.textInput = input} type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type your message here..." className="form-control"/>
              <span className="input-group-btn">                     
                  <button type="button" onClick={this.onSend.bind(this)} className="btn btn-flat btn-primary">Send</button>
                  </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Mas se eu quiser, pegar o que digitar no input text, e ao clicar no botão "Send", enviar esse conteudo digitado para (por exemplo), um <div> ou <span> ou <h1> no codigo? Tentei utilizar {this.state.texto}, mas ele so aparece o que eu estiver digitando no input simultaneamente:             
 <div className="direct-chat-text">{this.state.texto}</div>

Comment: @HenriqueHermes quando dizes _"enviar esse conteudo digitado"_ queres dizer mostrar dentro de uma `div` no mesmo componente ou noutro?

Comment: Para explicar melhor, fiz upload de um print de como eu gostaria que o codigo realizasse: https://imgur.com/iGDZ1Z4

Comment: @HenriqueHermes a lógica devia ser: escrever > clicar send > gravar no servidor > ajax sucess faz update do state > o render mostra a nova mensagem. Se este componente for responsável por atualizar o chatbox a lógica é optimista e penso que é melhor ser feito noutro sitio